# Slider Coming out of the Frame on increasing the Zoom of the Web Browser

Tags: html, css, opencart

The slider on my website [King Adler Ecommerce Website](http://kingadlerhomedecor.com) is coming out of the wrapper on zooming in the browser. I tested it on Google chrome, Mozilla and IE, it is the same everywhere. I think I will have to bring in a small change somewhere in the floating properties of the wrapper or the slider. But, I have no idea how to accomplish this. Please help me fix this with the least possible efforts.

```
    /* LAYOUT */
.primary-define .wrapper {
    width: 950px; /*changed by yuvi 1160*/ /*second change - 1060*/
    margin: 0 auto; /*0 10px*/
    /*position: relative; added by yuvi*/

}
.primary-define #column-left {
    float: left;
    width: 240px;
}
.primary-define #column-right {
    float: right;
    width: 240px;
}
.primary-define #column-left + #content,
.primary-define #column-right + #content {
    float: right;
    width: 650px; /*editing by yuvi*/
}
.primary-define #column-left + #content {
    margin-left: 60px;
}
.primary-define #column-right + #content {
    margin-right: 60px;
}
.primary-define #column-left + #column-right + #content {
    width: 520px;
}
.primary-define #content form {
    margin: 0;
}
```

---

```
/* CONTAINER */
.primary-define #container {
    z-index: 1;
    padding-top: 30px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

problem is not in slider but in whole layout if you set background in % then set container in %

```
.primary-define .wrapper {
    width: 80%; /*changed by yuvi 1160*/ /*second change - 1060*/
    margin: 0 auto; /*0 10px*/
    /*position: relative; added by yuvi*/

}
```

Comment: It didn't work for me. Is there any other way to achieve the same? Please help. Thanks

Comment: Anyone who can help me here?

Comment: as i can see in your website the white and black background are set in % but your page in px that is the only problem

Comment: Can you tell me where exactly am I supposed to make the change? Just paste the code where the correction is to be made. thanks :)